# change class of a cloned div with a button

Tags: jquery

I am cloning a div with a table in it. This div has a BLOCK class so it is visible. I would like to be able to have a button inside the div before the table, that gives the oportunity to hide this cloned div by changing it's class to a hidden class

```
var num = $('.class_of_div').length;
var newNum = num + 1;
```

Each cloned div has a new id. DIV_1 DIV_2 DIV_3.... each button also has new id's corresponding t it's div. So button_1 button_2 button_3....
The numbers after the tags are taken from the number of elements in another class.

these are my classes

```
.hidden{
     display: none;
 }

 .visible{
     display: block;
     margin-left: 20px;
 }
```

I would need to create a function with

```
.removeClass('.visible').addClass('.hidden')
```

but how can the button know that it must change the class of the current div in which is in? without changing classes of other old or new divs?

Hope all this was clear ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your button is inside the `div` that you want to edit it shouldn't be a problem to target that element using jQuery's [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) function.

Additionally, you are going to want to use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) when you declare your event handlers, so they are triggered in all clones.

```
$("body").on("click", "button", function() {
  $(this).closest("div").removeClass('.visible').addClass('.hidden');
});
```

See the runnable snippet below for an example.

```js
$("#wrapper").on("click", ".hide", function() {
  $(this).closest("div").hide("slow");
});
$("#wrapper").on("click", ".clone", function() {
  $(this).closest("div").clone().appendTo("#wrapper");
});
```

```css
.cloneable {
  margin: 5px;
  outline: 1px solid;
  background-color: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="cloneable">
    <button class="hide">Hide</button>
    <button class="clone">Clone</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how does it know that it must close the div it is currently in? for example the new div created has a button inside it. this new div has a id called Div_2, .closest("div") will automatically know that it only concerns the divs in which is is placed? sorry but I am learning Jquery so this is all very new ;)

Comment: That's what the `.closest()` function does. From the documentation: `Travels up the DOM tree until it finds a match for the supplied selector.` So the code I gave you will find the closest/nearest div that wraps the button and does whatever you want to specifically the one `div`. See the runnable snippet I added as an example.

Comment: thank you for the snippet. really helps to understand what happens. managed to run it in a simple example kind of like yours but unfortunately unable to run it in my page :( . I am unable to  vote up your answer to mark it as answered because i don't have enough rep. yet. But the answer to my question is there. Cheers. This will save a lot of hassle

Comment: It seems that when cloning, the function does not work anymore. is this due to the id's? does my new button need to have an id with the .closest() function? here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/adrienboufflet/7cps6fas/2/  note this is a quick example, did not put in the variable adding a +1 each time to the new elements ;)

Comment: thanks for your help. I am unable to mark it as a answer. I do not have enough reputation. is there another way to mark it as answer?

Comment: You don't have enough rep to upvote but anyone who asks can mark as an answer. There should be a check icon that you can click underneath the voting buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You can put different id's on all divs and do something like:

```
$('#div1').css("display", "block");
$('#div2').css("display", "none");
```

to show or hide the divs you want to.

Comment: same could also be accomplished by .hide()/.show() jQuery calls once you use it anyway